# Positioning view object underneath its nearest neighbor programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Programmatically (because Interface Builder was designed by Satan), how can I position one view object underneath another view object in the same way Interface Builder positions view objects by "nearest neighbor"?

If this is the first view object:

```
titleLabel.frame.size.width = view.frame.width - 32
titleLabel.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(16)
titleLabel.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(titleMargin + 32)
```

How would I position the second view object right underneath it? Must I create a function that gets the height of everything above it and set that as a top margin? Seems crude.

```
subtitleLabel.frame.size.width = view.frame.width - 32
subtitleLabel.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(16)
subtitleLabel.frame.origin.y = ???
```

I anticipate the solution to be much more complicated than the example lays out.

Comment: Using relationships between views rather than absolute coordinates is a good reason to adopt constraint-based layout.

Comment: That's the plan.

Comment: No, you can create constraints in code.  See: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without using constraints and auto-layout (which is totally independent of IB, by the way), change your last line:

```
titleLabel.frame.size.width = view.frame.width - 32
titleLabel.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(16)
titleLabel.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(titleMargin + 32)

subtitleLabel.frame.size.width = view.frame.width - 32
subtitleLabel.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(16)
subtitleLabel.frame.origin.y = titleLabel.frame.origin.y + titleLabel.frame.size.height
```

then, of course, if you're adding another element and want it to "follow below":

```
nextLabel.frame.size.width = view.frame.width - 32
nextLabel.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(16)
nextLabel.frame.origin.y = subtitleLabel.frame.origin.y + subtitleLabel.frame.size.height
```

If you have a lot of elements, either track a y-position variable or use object vars to maintain "previousObject" and "currentObject".

Just for example, anyway.